# Conditional join columns based on column value

Tags: sql-server-2014

I would like to conditionally join to a table on either one or two fields, depending on how a specific column is valued. I tried using a CASE statement to accomplish this but it is not working:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN ALT_TABLE B ON B.UNIT = A.UNIT AND B.USERID = A.USERID
INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE 2 ON CASE WHEN F.DEPARTMENT <> 'All' 
                                  THEN 'F.UNIT = A.UNIT AND F.DEPARTMENT = B.DEPARTMENT' 
                                 ELSE 'F.UNIT = A.UNIT' 
                                  END
```

However I am getting an error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'INNER'.

Is there another way to change what the join conditions are depending on a column value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```sql
...
INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE 2 ON F.UNIT = A.UNIT AND
     (F.DEPARTMENT = 'All' OR F.DEPARTMENT = B.DEPARTMENT)
```

You cannot "dynamic code" a query like you did without using dynamic SQL (bad idea here).

Also, if you analyze your logic, you will see that `UNIT` is always joined, and that `DEPARTMENT` only needs to be joined when `<> 'All'`, in other words: either it is `= 'ALL'` or we need the join condition.

Comment: I thought  had saw other posts where a `CASE` statement was used on the `Join`. Nonetheless this works just as well. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `CASE` but there is no point here